# Show text with <pre> or nl2br()?

Tags: php, html, pre, nl2br

When I think about it, why Should I use the function nl2br() instead of using the tags `<pre></pre>` ?

Thanks.

Comment: both have different functionality

Comment: If we see cost wise using of tags are more cheaper then php function

Comment: LIke there is with many things, using <pre> for adding <br>'s is just bad practise imo.

Comment: You're not limited to those options. You could also use the CSS property  [`white-space`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: This is like asking “Should I use an axe or a toothpick?” without saying what you would do with it.

Answer (score 4):

It's upto you and your desired output. There is no `Should` and `<pre>` is not just for new lines, `nl2br()` is limited to that.

> The pre element represents a block of preformatted text, in which structure is represented by typographic conventions rather than by elements.

**[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/pre.html)**

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string

**[Source](http://php.net/nl2br)**

Spot and prioritize the difference yourself :)